# Regular expression to match blocks of { } in JSON

Tags: regex, find-and-replace, json

I have the following piece of JSON that occurs on about a hundred and fifty files in an application I am working on.

```json
        {
            path: "/cms/scenarios/:scenarioId/impacts/add",
            name: "Add Impact",
            mini: "",
            icon: faPlusCircle,
            component: ImpactsAdd,
            layout: "/admin"
        },
        {
            hide: true,
            path: "/cms/scenarios/:scenarioId/impacts/edit/:impactId",
            name: "Edit Impact",
            mini: "",
            component: ImpactsEdit,
            layout: "/admin"
        },
        {
            hide: true,
            path: "/cms/scenarios/:scenarioId/impacts/delete/:impactId",
            name: "Delete Impact",
            mini: "",
            component: ImpactsDelete,
            layout: "/admin"
        },
        {
            path: "/cms/scenarios/:scenarioId/impacts",
            name: "List Impacts",
            icon: faClipboardList,
            mini: "",
            component:ImpactsList,
            layout: "/admin"
        },
```

We need to place the element at the bottom of the JSON at the top, so what I was hoping to do was something akin to this (pseudo code):

```
pattern1 = {(.*)/add(.*)}
pattern2 = {(.*)/edit/(.*)}
pattern3 = {(.*)/delete(.*)}
pattern4 = {(.*)/list(.*)}    <--- needs to be moved to the top
```

So I could essentially match: /patt1 patt2 patt3 patt4/ - and then replace with patt4 patt1 patt2 patt3.

I am fine with writing the script, or using IDE to do the find/replace, I just need to figure out the pattern. I am having trouble matching the 'matching' pairs of brackets along with the new lines.

What expression would I use to match the brackets with their respective pair, and also match the new lines repeatedly?

This is as far as I got =(

```
{\n(.*)\/add"([.\n]*) (to match the 'Add' block)
```

Comment: I confess that I'm not able to understand exactly what you want to do. Please add further explanations.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Why don't you use a JSON parser?

Comment: Linux/Windows/Mac ? Can we use `sed` | `perl` ? `jq`?

Comment: The last block of the json, I need to move it to the top of the JSON blocks.

{ 1, 2, 3, 4 } => { 4, 1, 2, 3 }